# Make CSS grid row grow when content gets bigger

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using a grid layout for a month-view where each week is another grid layout.
For each event, I'm using something like `grid-column: 5/span 2; top: 1rem;` to layer the events on top of the calendar days, but when the number of events get too many, they overflow.

[image]

I can set overflow hidden on `section.week`, but then the events simply get chopped off which is not any better.

[image]

Is there a way to make the whole calendar grow when the events start overflowing a week, even if it means having to scroll up and down to see the whole calendar?
Open to other suggestions too.

```css
:host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section.month {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section.week {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content repeat(7, 1fr);
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

section.week > * + * {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

section.week > * {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

section.closure {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px red;
    align-self: baseline;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 1px;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    grid-row: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="month">
    <section class="week">
        <div class="week-of-year">
            32
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 2/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 3/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 4/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 5/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 6/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 7/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 8/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="week">
        <div class="week-of-year">
            33
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 2/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 3/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">15</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 4/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 5/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">17</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 6/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">18</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 7/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">19</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 8/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">20</div>
        </div>

        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 5/span 2; top: 1rem;">
            Some text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; top: 3.5rem;">
            Some other text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; top: 6rem;">
            Some more text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; top: 8.5rem;">
            More irrelevant text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; top: 11rem;">
            Some other text
        </section>
    </section>
    <section class="week">
        <div class="week-of-year">
            34
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 2/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 3/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 4/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 5/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 6/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 7/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 8/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Instead of `overflow: hidden`, what about `overflow: auto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjust the **closure** elements using grid-row instead of **top**

To get the borders of the days to adapt to the new dimension, you need also to set **grid-row** for them to 1/7 or higher, based on the maximum number of additional rows that are needed.

```css
:host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section.month {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content;
    grid-auto-rows: min-content;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section.week {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 20px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

section.week > * + * {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

section.week > * {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.day, .week-of-year {
    grid-row: 1/99;
}
.week-of-year {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
section.closure {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px red;
    align-self: baseline;
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 1px;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    grid-row: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="month">
    <section class="week">
        <div class="week-of-year">
            32
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 2/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 3/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 4/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 5/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 6/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 7/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 8/span 1; grid-row: 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="week">
        <div class="week-of-year">
            33
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 2/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 3/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">15</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 4/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 5/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">17</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 6/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">18</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 7/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">19</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 8/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">20</div>
        </div>

        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 5/span 2; grid-row: 2">
            Some text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; grid-row: 3">
            Some other text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; grid-row: 4">
            Some more text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; grid-row: 5">
            More irrelevant text
        </section>
        <section class="closure" style="grid-column: 3/span 3; grid-row: 6">
            Some other text
        </section>
    </section>
    <section class="week">
        <div class="week-of-year">
            34
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 2/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 3/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 4/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 5/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 6/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 7/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day past" style="grid-column: 8/span 1">
            <div class="day-number">.</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: this is very close to what I have in mind.
Is it possible to also make the div.week-of-year fill all the rows? (give it a background colour, and you'll see it only fills the first) I've tried giving it grid-row: 1/-1, but it remains a single row and doesn't expand to fill all the rows like the div.day elements. 

Since the number of events could be anything, it would be nice to not have to calculate the row-span for each week when CSS can do it.

Comment: I noticed that I can just set the grid-row: 1/99 and it'll get the job done.

Comment: Updated the snippet to adjust week-of-year, also using your advise about grid-row :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using position: relative and the top property to place events, use grid rows for your events. By default, the grid items will stack and create new rows as needed.Remove the grid-row: 1 you've specified for each closure (event).

```css
:host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

section.month {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section.week {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content repeat(7, 1fr);
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

section.week > * + * {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

section.week > * {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

section.closure {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px red;
    align-self: baseline;
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 1px;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML Changes:
Remove the grid-row: 1 from each section.closure. And you also don't need to specify the top property for them anymore.